What was the contribution of the students of the University of Dhaka in establishing Pakistan?

Bengali language movement

This article says that the students of the University of Dhaka played the primary role in instating Bengali as the state language of Pakistan.
I wonder what their role was during the Pakistan Movement (1936-1947).
This link says nothing.
What was the contribution of the students of the University of Dhaka during the Pakistan Movement?
Did they have any? I guess, a big NO.
If not, why?

Do you mean only those who were students at the University of Dhaka, or do you also count graduates of the University of Dhaka? Of the main leaders of the various groups mentioned, do you know who graduated from where?

@JonCuster, Only the current students at that time. Not the alumnai.

@JonCuster, Student's movement or student's protest are not the same as alumnai movement or alumnai protest.

@JonCuster, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationwide_student_anti-war_strike_of_1970 --- do you think this was done by alumnai?

I was trying to clarify your question. Clearly multiple leaders of the movement over the years did graduate from the University of Dhaka. But on-campus demonstrations by students probably did not do much, overall, compared with the activities of the larger political groups.

@JonCuster, So, Pakistan Movement was done by elders, but they were absent during the Language Movement and vice versa. This needs explanation.
